# In a gimp (pythonfu) plug-in, is there any way for the plugin itself to determine its installation path?

Tags: plugins, gimp, gimpfu

Suppose that a gimp (PyGIMP) plugin needs access to some arbitrary image files distributed with the plug-in.  Given that the set can be installed by the user anywhere, is there a way for the plug-in itself to determine its own installation path to use as a path prefix for those resources (e.g., images)??  I have tried searching the pdb, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in all python code, you can find your code origin using `os.path.realpath(__file__)`, but since Gimp calls the script by its full path you can also use `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])`.

However:

- There are several variables that contain various directory locations: `gimp.directory`, `gimp.data_directory`, `gimp.locale_directory`, `gimp.plug_in_directory`.
- If the script is installed at the system level, resources are best put in `os.path.join(gimp.data_directory,'scripts')`